# 3 tables and 2 independent JOINs with CONCAT expressions

Tags: mysql, left-join, group-concat

I have the following 3 tables with IDs

Table: users

```
user | name
  1  | Joe
  2  | John
```

Table: user_id1

```
user | id1
  1  |   2
  1  |   3
  2  |   5
```

Table: user_id2

```
user | id2
  1  |   3
  1  |   4
```

I would like to get the following result for each user

```
name | ids 1 | ids 2
 Joe | 2,3   | 3,4
 John| 5     | NULL
```

I use this query:

```
SELECT
  user.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(user_id1.id1) AS "ids1",
  GROUP_CONCAT(user_id2.id2) AS "ids2"

FROM users

LEFT JOIN user_id1
  ON user_id1.user=users.user

LEFT JOIN user_id2
  ON user_id2.user=users.user
```

But I get this result:

```
name | ids1    | ids2
Joe  | 2,2,3,3 | 3,4,3,4
John | 5       | NULL
```

What is wrong?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DISTINCT should solve it

```
SELECT
  user.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id1.id1) AS "ids1",
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id2.id2) AS "ids2"

FROM users

LEFT JOIN user_id1
  ON user_id1.user=users.user

LEFT JOIN user_id2
  ON user_id2.user=users.user
```